# Trying read csv file into java, set each filed as object and save into javalist, but missing a value in the csv file

Tags: java, csv, object, arraylist

i m trying read csv data to java, and set each fields as object and add into the arraylist, but i got a different csv file which is missing one vaules, the error is java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6.

[image: CSV files]

```
public void loadAircraftData(Path p) throws DataLoadingException {  
    try {
        //open the file
        BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(p);
        
        //read the file line by line
        String line = "";
        
        //skip the first line of the file - headers
        reader.readLine();
        
        
        while( (line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            //each line has fields separated by commas, split into an array of fields
            String[] fields = line.split(",");
            
            
            //put some of the fields into variables: check which fields are where atop the CSV file itself
            String tailcode = fields[0];
            String model = fields[1];
            String type = fields[2];
            //Manufacturer manufacturer = fields[3];
            String staringPoistion = fields[4];
            int seats = Integer.parseInt(fields[5]);
            int cabincrewrequired= Integer.parseInt(fields[6]);
            
            
            //create an Aircraft object, and set (some of) its properties
            Aircraft a = new Aircraft();
            a.setTailCode(tailcode);
            a.setModel(model);
            a.setTypeCode(type);
            //a.setManufacturer(Manufacturer);
            a.setStartingPosition(staringPoistion);;
            a.setSeats(seats);
            a.setCabinCrewRequired(cabincrewrequired);
            a.setManufacturer(Manufacturer.AIRBUS);
            a.setManufacturer(Manufacturer.FOKKER);
            a.setManufacturer(Manufacturer.EMBRAER);
            
            
            //add the aircraft to our list
            aircraft.add(a);
```

Comment: Could you upload the content of the file in csv format?

Comment: The second row has no value in column cabincrewrequired. Thus, your fields array has only 6 elements in the second iteration. Your code needs to be aware of missing fields. If you debug through your code step by step you clearly see what is happening.

Comment: I know the errors, i just dont have how to make my code aware of missing fields in csv files

Comment: You could iterate over the length of the fields array and then setting the fields, depending on the index

Comment: how excatly should i do that ? using a loop?

Comment: Yes, a simple for loop should be enough. That way, you can't run into out-of-bound exceptions (if your loop boundaries are set correctly). And inside the loop, you just need to check the index with an if or switch, to set the corresponding variable

Comment: Oh ye sorry about that, i m still trying use the loop to filter the index, but i cant find a way do it .

Comment: @JiayaoWang - I am talking about this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65597702/what-type-of-value-should-i-store-in-hashmap-with-date-and-intger-in-java/65597917#65597917

Answer (score 0):

I have an alternative solution that is different that use a loop. My idea is to have a method that checks if the index exists and return the value of this index, if not exist I can provide a default value.

**Class**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] fields = "2,2,2,2,2,2,".split(",");

        int seats = Integer.parseInt(getValue(fields, 5, "0"));
        int cabincrewrequired = Integer.parseInt(getValue(fields, 6, "0"));

        System.out.println(seats);
        System.out.println(cabincrewrequired);
    }

    private static String getValue(String[] fields, int index, String defaultValue) {
        return fields.length > index ? fields[index] : defaultValue;
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
2
0
```